# NDVI error in ERDAS

Tags: erdas-imagine, ndvi, landsat-7, default-value

I have created a NDVI image from Landsat 7 data using ERDAS (veg_NDVI.gmd). This model was already in ERDAS 9.3. After creation the final output visually highlighting vegetative areas but the value showing 0-255. But theoretically it is known that the NDVI value ranges from (-1) to (+1). Please let me be clear about this confusion and suggest the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Erdas provides an option to stretch the NDVI values from the typical floating point NDVI range (-1 to 1) to 8-bit unsigned integer (0 - 255). This can be handy to reduce file size from floating point to 8-bit unsigned integer (0 - 255) and stretch the values to the full pixel depth of the image. However, it also reduces the sensitivity of the index. You can create NDVI doing the following: `Interpreter > Spectral Enhancement > Indices`. In this dialogue box, make sure to *not* select "Stretch to Unsigned 8-bit". There is also a [you tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFbBB8Oy2As) that can walk you through the process.

[image]